# Convolution of fraction function

Tags: integration, convolution

I know that convolution is defined:
$$f*g=\int f(x-y)\cdot g(y) \, dy $$

How to develop below functions to convolution equation

$$\int {f(x-y) \over g(y)} \, dy =\text{ ???}$$

and

$$\int {f(x-y) \over g^2(y)} \, dy=\text{ ???} $$

Thank you so much

Comment: I don't understand very well but my try will be $f*\frac{1}{g}$ and $f*\frac{1}{g^2}$

Comment: @lartilage: Are you sure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $h(x)=\frac{1}{g(x)}$ then:
$$f*\frac{1}{g}=f*h=\int {f(x-y)h(y)} \, dy \int {f(x-y)\frac{1}{g(y)}} \, dy$$
Second assume $h(x)=\frac{1}{g^2(x)}$ then:
$$f*\frac{1}{g^2}=f*h=\int {f(x-y)h(y)} \, dy \int {f(x-y)\frac{1}{g^2(y)}} \, dy$$